# how do you check if a string is at the end of a line?

Tags: java, string, file

I am having trouble detecting if a string is at the end of a line. For example, in the string:

```
"hey hi
 hello"
```

How do you detect if the hi is at the end of the line? I am reading in strings from a file, so is the end of line character any different in files?

Comment: Search for `"\n"` which is the escape character for a new line.

Comment: You have to say how you're reading the file, as a lot of methods like `readLine()` or `nextLine()` strip the newline characters, so if you just searched for it, you'd never find it.

Comment: @aamit915 I am reading in the file using `new Scanner(new File("KLSadd.tex")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();`

Comment: Hey! Did you mean a `string` or a `word`?

Comment: @PaulVargas,  a string

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `BufferedReader` or similar object to read the file and just read a line at a time with the `readLine()` method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using the MULTILINE flag with regular expressions.

```
// this allows spaces between 'hi' and the end of the line
yourString.matches("(?m).*hi\s*$");

// this does not allow spaces
yourString.matches("(?m).*hi%");
```

Answer (score 0):

The new line character has different representations on different operating systems. It may be

- LF - '\n'
- CR - '\r'
- CR+LF - '\r\n'

You can check it the next character is one the previous mentioned, depending on the input OS.

You use `StringTokinizer` or `BufferedReader.readLine()` for line reading or string splitting

Answer (score 0):

getline(istream,string) is reading input to the character end_of_line you can get last string in line from readed string.